# Azure Table Storage Entity Row/Primary Key as Attribute for existing properties

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I already have entity migrated from EntityFramework. 
I'm don't want override some propeties and Convert it to string

```
public class User : TableEntity, ITableStorageEntity<int, Guid>
{        
    [RowKey]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [PartitionKey]
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
```

It's possible ? I don't want override ReadEntity/WriteEntity.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to override the properties or the Read/Write methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your class is already based on TableEntity, you might want to try to override/replace the row key and partition key property of TableEntity using the 'new' keyword instead.

```
public class User : TableEntity
{
    [IgnoreProperty]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [IgnoreProperty]
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }

    public new string PartitionKey { get { return ID.ToString(); } set { ID = Guid.Parse(value); } }

    public new string RowKey { get { return LanguageID.ToString(); } set { LanguageID = int.Parse(value); } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not a big fan of 'new' modifier. In my opinion it is non-OOP approach.

I will suggest following

```
public class ConsumerApplicationEntity : TableEntity
{
    public ConsumerApplicationEntity(string applicationKey, string applicationSecret)
        : base(applicationKey, applicationSecret)
    {

    }

    [IgnoreProperty]
    public string ApplicationKey
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PartitionKey;
        }
        set
        {
            this.PartitionKey = value;
        }
    }

    [IgnoreProperty]
    public string ApplicationSecret
    {
        get
        {
            return this.RowKey;
        }
        set
        {
            this.RowKey = value;
        }
    }
}
```